# Python: automatically generate package descriptive list for project

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, python-packaging

I am developing a Python project with a brief *requirements.txt* file.
It was asked to me to compile a table with, for every package present:

1. library name
2. library version
3. description
4. licence
5. website

Does it exists an automatic procedure to obtain it from Python/Pycharm? I've seen that information can be retrieved from `pip show` also.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a guide how to setup a requirements file https://medium.com/@boscacci/why-and-how-to-make-a-requirements-txt-f329c685181e
and https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_freeze/

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

will write a file with the requirements of installed packages. A guide for Pycharm can be found here https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/managing-dependencies.html#configure-requirements

Another way is to use *yolk* https://pypi.org/project/yolk3k/ for python 3 or https://pypi.org/project/yolk/

Then you can do, for example

```
yolk -l -f License,Author,Home-page
```

to list what you want from the dependencies

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: this is not an answer to my question

Comment: this is still not an answer to my question

Comment: @Lore sry for misunderstanding your question, I've updated my answer with yolk, hope that's what you are looking for!

Comment: Have you tried yolk3k? Got that error too, but had to install yolk3k since I use python 3

Comment: ok yolk3k seems very good! How can I use it only for packages in requirements.txt?

Comment: Maybe you could install the requirements in a virtenv and use yolk in it?